# Can we say "wish to do something" for things that can only be achieved by good luck or magic?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

Say, Alibaba was trapped in a cave and it was impossible for him to get out of the cave.

**Is it correct for Alibaba to say these at that moment?**:

-"*I wish to get out of here*"

or

-"*I wish that I could get out of here*"

or

-"*I wish for myself to get out of here*"

or

-"*I wish for getting out of here*"

Comment: Which of them would you use Tom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Alibaba talking to a genie?

In fact, is Alibaba talking to anyone at all??  If he is alone in a cave he probably just doesn't talk. Or if he does begin to talk to himself, he would say "اريد ان اخرج"

If he doesn't have a Genie,  he would be more likely to say "I hope to get out" or "I want to get out".  Using "wish" is possible, in the form "I wish I could get out of here" but less likely.

Comment: I think he would say to himself "I wish I could get out of here". If the genie offered him a wish (three wishes?) he would say "I wish to get out of here."